# Can somebody fill the gap between the rules and Mujahid's understanding of the rules?

Tags: discussion

Question [17085](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/17085/which-one-should-we-believe?noredirect=1#comment31463_17085) and [17125](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/17125/what-was-the-reason-that-aisha-refused-mentioning-ali-bin-abi-talib-by-his-name) were closed by [Mujahid](https://islam.stackexchange.com/users/9/mujahid-%D9%85%D8%AC%D8%A7%D9%87%D8%AF). **Why**? Can somebody let me know what Mujahid has been up to?

Comment: Actually, no, they were not.  I closed them myself, and I told you exactly why I did so in comments.

Comment: I am not sure if there was a good reason to close them, but I see don't any reason to delete the questions.